# Linq to Sql isolation level

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, transactions, isolation-level

What is the default transaction isolation level does InsertOnSubmit call use in LinqToSql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an explicit [`TranscationScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) object constructed with the non-default constructor that takes a [`TransactionOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionoptions.aspx) argument. This way you will have the desired isolation level and won't wave to wonder what the default is. Scott Hanselman has an example in [Getting LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities to use NOLOCK](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx)

As a side node the transaction isolation level is largely irrelevant on inserts, as the isolation level refer to the behavior of *reads* not writes.

Comment: There is no UpdateOnSubmit in Linq To Sql, so you have to lazy "query" the row, change the attributes, commit it. What happens in this case? It's executed as a single transaction right?